# Remove <br> tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Good Day.

Actually it is the wordpress site but i need the general solution using jquery(if feasible)
I trying to remove the 
 tag next to end of the div.

See I am using the div as like here

```
    <div class="one_third">
<p>This is for testing</p>
    </div>
    <br> <!--This one -->
    <div class="one_third">
    </div>
    <br><!--This one -->
    <div class="one_third">
    </div>
    <br><!--This one -->
```

In the above example i am using the class of one_third in a div inside this div i am using br tag too. But all i am want to remove the br tag which is in outside the div i mean in the end of the div in jquery.

```
</div>
<br>
```

I am not sure how to do this in jquery (Actually i try with wordpress disable wpautop is removing the br tag which is inside the div too (I don't want to remove the br tag inside the div only outside the div i mean end of the div )).

Any suggestion would be great :)

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the next sibling of the element with class `one_third`

```
$('.one_third').next('br').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NDj3K/)

Comment: This is the answer you're looking for @fresher

Comment: @NicholasHazel using jQuery, yes it is but adeneo's answer seems more appropriate even i don't know wordpress

Comment: Very true, now that I look at it.

Comment: Or `$(".one_third + br").remove()`

Answer (score 7):

You should just place the HTML on one line.
wpautop inserts `<br>` on newlines, so placing the HTML code on one line avoids the entire issue.

```
<div class="one_third"><p>This is for testing</p></div><div class="one_third"></div><div class="one_third"></div>
```

The way you structure the markup is everything when wpautop is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `next()` and `remove()` methods in jQuery for that

```
$(".one_third").next('br').remove();
```

Comment: then we can use next()

Comment: This will remove all the `<br>` elements _inside_ the `<div>`'s. You should edit your answer.

Comment: Your two lines of code are identical. The `.next()` method always returns 1 element at the most.

Answer (score 3):

A non JavaScript solution would be a simple CSS sibling selector

```
.one_third + br { 
    display : none; 
}
```

If you really want to use jQuery, you can use the same selector and use `remove()`

```
$(".one_third + br").remove();
```

Comment: CSS would be the best solution since it will just work, no worrying about the page state when JS runs causing the page to flicker as it redraws. Unless you like that redrawing.